# How to make the long text message within the div

Tags: css

i have a long message inside the div box, and i am looking for a way to show the that text message within the div with scroll bar (vertical) and i have two links to it as you can see:
1)disclaimer
2)Behavior
the above links are hyperlink so when i click those links i display the below divs based on the selection. so is that possible to show the div underneath the hyperlink with nice model div or something?

i am not a CSS guy so if possible make the div box look awesome :)

```
<span ><a href="#" >Disclaimer-1</a></span> <span class="slide1">
        &nbsp; &nbsp; | &nbsp; &nbsp; <a href="#" class="slide1">Behavior</a></span>
    <div id="one" >
        Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s 
    </div>
    <div id="second" >
          Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s    
    </div>
```

Comment: what do you mean by: and when i click on the div i just need the div to be underneath the links.

Comment: i have updated my question, sorry about that.

Comment: Are you looking to click the links and jump down the page to the content, or do you want to reveal the div with the associated content?  They are both doable but very different.

Comment: reveal the div with the associated content, i have the code that works based on the associated content but i am looking for a way to beautify the div box, i have attached the pic.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want a scroll bar, set a `height` and then make the `overflow` value `auto` or `scroll`.

```
div#one,
div#two
{
    height: 120px;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

As for your latest edit, you're looking at JavaScript to implement something like that.

Comment: Do you mean set a height?  He wants a vertical scroll bar, so you need to restrict the height or the div will just stretch.

Comment: @SurrealDreams Yeah, I meant height which you can see by my actual example code, just a typo ;P

Comment: Just making sure we were all on the same page there.  :)

Answer (score 0):

Hi for make scroll bar in left and format the page please find basic css you can use.

```
<style type="text/css">
        #one{
            overflow-y: scroll;
            padding:  15px;
            height: 150px;
            line-height: 25px;
            margin: 20px 0px 20px 0px;
        }
        #second{
            overflow-y: scroll;
            padding:  15px;
            height: 150px;
            line-height: 25px;
        }
        span a{
         padding-left:15px;
         color:blue;
         text-decoration: none;
         }
        span a:hover{
         padding-left:15px;
         color:blue;
         text-decoration: none;
        }

    </style>
```

Please specify the point `when i click on the div i just need the div to be underneath the links`.

thanks..